# Find number of array element that can be formed with add/subtract operation of two other number with third number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, data-structures

Given three numbers d, a, b and an array of integers. We can add/subtract a or b to d any number of times. We are supposed to find the count of numbers in the array which can be formed by applying these operations to d.

Example: if array is `[14, 15, 63]` and `d = 4`, `a = 7` and `b = 9;`

Then output should be 2. 
As
`14 = 4 + (9 - 7) + (9 - 7) + (9 - 7) + (9 - 7) + (9 - 7)
63 = 4 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 7 + 7`
But 15 cannot be obtains with any combination. thus output is 2.

Kindly suggest an algorithm for calculating this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 15 = 4 + 9 + 9 - 7 - 7 + 9 + 9 - 7 - 7 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 - 7 - 7 - 7 - 7 - 7 - 7. And in fact, you can form any number because 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 - 9 - 9 - 9 = 1. In general, if the [GCD(a,b)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) is 1, then you can form any number.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Can you also suggest a common logic to solve problem when GCD(a, b) is not equal to 1?

Comment: After analysis, here is the solution I came up. find difference between array element and d. If is this difference is divisible by GCD(a, b) then array element can be formed with given conditions. Otherwise not. Thanks  user3386109 for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little more detail to @user3386109's comment,

> Given three numbers d, a, b and an array of integers. We can add/subtract a or b to d any number of times. We are supposed to find the count of numbers in the array which can be formed by applying these operations to d.

Let an element in array be x,

Now, say `x = d + a*i + b*j`, where i and j are any integers. If this needs to hold true, then `x - d = a*i + b*j`. 
Lets see what the right hand term has to say,

From [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

> Bézout's identity — Let a and b be integers with greatest common divisor d. Then, there exist integers x and y such that ax + by = d. More generally, the integers of the form ax + by are exactly the multiples of d.

We see that `a*i + b*j`  are exactly the multiples of `GCD(a,b)`. So the difference `x-d` must be divisible by `GCD(a,b)` like @AshutoshTiwari  pointed out.